# Is there any way to get a copy of Pillar of Prayer translated by Menachem Kallus

Tags: jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism, baal-shem-tov

In my search to learn about about the Baal Shem Tov's teachings I came across this book which sounds like it is exactly the sort of book I've been searching for:

https://fonsvitae.com/product/pillar-of-prayer/

Unfortunately, it appears to have sold out its print run, and used copies are selling on Amazon for hundreds of a dollars. Does anybody know if this book might be available in the future with either a second paper printing or an ebook version?

Comment: did you try contacting the publisher. They might have some copies left even though it's not showing up on the website

Comment: Thanks, I wrote to the publisher, I'll update here if I hear back from them